# IOS 5 - XCode 4 - SIGABRT when application starts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My application has started throwing a SIGABRT exception as soon as I begin to debug. I can not determine why and XCode 4 doesn't seem to give a detailed stack trace but rather just breaks in the main function.

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown before any of my viewcontrollers even begin to load. The AppDelegate's applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions never gets called either. How can I debug this in XCode 4? Totally stumped.

Thanks..

Comment: put a breakpoint in app delegate.m `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and check if that is reached

Comment: I should have mentioned this. It is not. The AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching is never called.

Comment: Problem is somewhere else. Not in the main function. Please post your code for `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: Please see in your MainWindow.xib file.. Is every thing proper there?

Comment: Have you added an Exception Breakpoint for All, Break On Throw? You might catch it with that.

Comment: @ParthBhatt the applicationDidFinishLaunching has not been modified from the template's orginal version. It just returns, "YES".

Answer (score 0):

did you set you MainWindow.nib file in "Main nib file base name" in info.plist? and error is not in the main function

**Note: in XCode 4.x.x most of exception throws to the main function.**